iframe prevents parent events
I have an iframe in my page and in my parent document I have some event listeners listening to click and drag (document.addEventListener , window.addEventListener)
When I drag or click out of the iframe, all events work. But when I do the action in iframe, none of listener work
I guess it's becuse iframe has its own window object and parent window become unfocus, is there anyway to fix this problem?
The iframe is a 3rd party website, I cannot edit its content and because of CORS issue I cannot inject JS

Does this answer your question? addEventListener to iFrame

No, I cannot read iframe.contentWindow.body because of Failed to read a named property 'body' from 'Window': Blocked a frame with origin "***" from accessing a cross-origin frame. error

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Yes, I know. I have CORS limitations

There is no other way to do it as far as I know while using iframe. This is to prevent clickjacking.
